# Android Checkbox app:checked = true, doesnt show checkmark

Tags: android

When using a view model to set checkbox attributes, if app:checked is set programmatically, it does not show a a check just an outline like in the picture.  Everything else works as expected.  Has anyone seen this before or can help?

[Notice the first checkbox is not checked, and app:checked = true is set programmatically using a viewModel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjPR9.png)

Comment: add your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text"
        android:checked="true"
        />
```

or

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```